# add multipe sub menus using add_submenu_page

Tags: add-submenu-page

I need to add multiple submeus under a single parent admin menu. i can add submenu using following syntax.

```
function register_my_sub_admin() {
    add_submenu_page( '/pluginname/includes/admin-menu.php',
        'title',
        'menu_title',
        'manage_options',
        '/pluginname/includes/submenu.php',
        '',
        plugins_url( 'pluginname/images/icon.png' )
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_sub_admin' );
```

Since I have more than 10 submenus to register as above, i have to duplicate the above code as much as needed.

So thinking, whether can I use some foreach loop or someother array method to do one code block and register all submenu pages via one action hook / function.

Will something like below can make this happen ?

```
$sub_menu       = array();
    $sub_menu['page_title'] = array('page1','page2');
    $sub_menu['menu_title'] = array('title1','title2');
    $sub_menu['capability'] ='manage_options';
    $sub_menu['slug']   = array('wp-admin.php','wp-login.php');
    $sub_menu['function'] ='';

    foreach ($sub_menu as $key => $value ){
        add_submenu_page( '/pluginname/includes/admin-menu.php',
            $key,$key,$key,$key,$key,
            plugins_url( 'pluginname/images/icon.png' )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a loop is almost always a good solution to avoid to copy-paste code.

you just need to use a array of datas like that :

```
$submenus = [
    [
        "page_title" => "page1",
        "menu_title" => "title1",
        "slug" => "wp-admin.php",
    ],
    [
        "page_title" => "page2",
        "menu_title" => "title2",
        "slug" => "wp-login.php",
    ],
];


foreach ($submenus as $value) {

    add_submenu_page(
        '/pluginname/includes/admin-menu.php',
        $value["page_title"],
        $value["menu_title"],
        'manage_options',
        $value["slug"],
        '',
        plugins_url( 'pluginname/images/icon.png' )
    );


}
```

Comment: Great, This is exactly what i was trying to achieve. one more thing, Is there a way to fold these items under the parent slug and expand on click of parent slug ?

Comment: yes it's possible, create a new question for that.